# Writing values in serial fails to update immediately

Tags: cratedb

I am trying to write many values into the create-io DB using a python script.
Since crate does not support an auto-incrementer for fiels like ID, I query the last ID and use (+1) for the next one.
However, when I send a "insert into..." command, the data is not written immediately. So even if I close the connection and call

`select count(id) from mytable`

I still receive the old id counter.
For now, I am forced to use

`time.sleep(0.5)`

after each insert, which is "not good" .

Can someone guide me here into a direction?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CrateDB is eventual consistent (https://crate.io/docs/reference/en/0.54.4/storage_consistency.html) but provides e.g. read-after write consistency.

so if you query a document by its primary key - it will be immediately available.

if this is not enough or you can't query by primary key you can issue the `REFRESH TABLE`command - but this comes at a performance penalty.